# Sufficient condition for two operators being identical on Hilbert space

Tags: operator-theory, hilbert-spaces, inner-products

Considering two bounded linear operators $S,T$ in $\mathcal{B}(X)$, where $X$ is a complex Hilbert space.

If $\def\norm#1#2{\langle {#1},{#2}\rangle} \norm{Sx}{x} = \norm{Tx}{x}$ for all $x\in X$, do we have $S=T$?

Furthermore, for another bounded linear operator $A$, if $\norm{Ax_n}{x_n}$ converges to $\norm{A x}{x}$ for all $x_n\to x$, does the convergence has a name?

Comment: When $S$ and $T$ are positive definite, this amounts to saying "is it possible for a norm to be induced by two different inner products?". The answer is no because of the polarization identity, so in this case $S=T$. Since the proof of the polarization identity does not use the definiteness of the inner product, this will also hold provided $S$ and $T$ are merely self-adjoint. As Vladimir pointed out, it can fail when one or the other is not self-adjoint.

Comment: @Ian: The proof of the polarization identity does not use self-adjointness either;)

Comment: I was thinking of $f(x,y)=\langle Sx,y \rangle$ as an "indefinite inner product", i.e. a function which satisfies all the axioms of an inner product except positive definiteness. It is both symmetric-bilinear (or symmetric-sesquilinear, in the complex case) iff $S$ is self-adjoint. But you're right, you can apply the polarization identity to the underlying inner product here, and everything is OK.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $X=\mathbf{R}^2$, $S=0$, $T=\begin{pmatrix}0&1\\-1&0\end{pmatrix}$.
In the complex case the polarization identity expresses $(Sx,y)$ via $(S(x\pm y),x\pm y)$ and $(S(x\pm iy),x\pm iy)$, so the criterion is true.

As for the second question, from the preceding discussion we see that this is just weak convergence.

Comment: Yes, you are right, here is what I meant.

Comment: I apologize for forgetting mentioning that it is a complex Hilbert space. Otherwise it makes little sense to discuss about spectrum.

Comment: @Ian: no it does not, take $x=\begin{pmatrix}1\\i\end{pmatrix}$.

Comment: Why polarization leads to identity?

Comment: You know by assumption that $(S(x+y),x+y)=(T(x+y),x+y)$ etc. and conclude by polarization identity that $(Sx,y)=(Tx,y)$ for all $x,y\in H$. Hence $S=T$.

Comment: what do you mean polarization? I obtained $\langle Ax,y\rangle + \langle A y, x\rangle = 0$, with $S-T = A$. By manipulating $y$, I concluded $A = 0$ and hence $S = T$. It seems no polarization is used.

Comment: @newbie Some questions give the impression that those who ask have been banned on google and wikipedia. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polarization_identity

Comment: I do know what polarization is but I did not used in the proof. That is my question.

Comment: You did not and I did. That is my answer.

Comment: So would you be so kind as to explain how you used it?

Comment: The polarization identity say that $\langle Sx,y\rangle=\frac14\sum_{j=0}^3\langle S(x+i^jy),x+i^jy\rangle$. A similar fomula holds with $T$ instead of $S$. Since we know that $\langle Su,u\rangle=\langle Tu,u\rangle$ for all $u$, we take $u=x+i^jy$ and conclude that $\langle Sx,y\rangle=\langle Tx,y\rangle$ for all $x,y$ and hence $S=T$. I have already briefly explained that in my comment of Jun 12, 20:52. If you really wish to achieve something in mathematics, you should really use your brain more intensively rather than depend on others in each and every detail.